# What's the easiest way to create a software-controlled 220V electricity interruptor?

Tags: power-supply, usb, relay

As the title says, I'm looking for an easy way to interrupt a 220V electrical cable and to write a software that controls the interruption.

I imagine there are some kind of relays or contactors which can be controlled by the PC through a USB connection. I tried googling these, but did not find anything that promised to do what I need.

I'm a software developer, so I think I won't have problems doing the PC side of the thing. However, my knowledge and experience in EE is limited, so I'd prefer if I could just buy a device with a USB and power connection, instead of crambling something together manually.

Any hint is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found several USB controlled relay modules, but unlike many others [this one](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/usb_rly02tech.htm) does not require a separate power supply; it's powered from the USB bus.

[image]

The module uses a virtual COM driver to control the relays from your PC. So any programming language able to talk over UART can be used to control the module.

On the same site you'll find modules with 8 relays as well.

Answer (score 0):

I control 120VAC and 240VAC loads all over my property using X10. I can hop onto any PC and manually control any load, or program timers, or even tie loads to turn on or off according to sunup or sundown. I can also set parameters to control loads according to various inputs or status from other loads. I created a clickable icon map based on device addresses. I can also click on any device on a 2D map on the screen to see its status or to control it.